# An asymptotic expansion for $(1 + \frac{x}{n})^n$.

Tags: asymptotics

I am trying to work out an asymptotic expansion for the function 
$$f(x, n) = \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$ in the following sense.  For all $k \geq 1$, let $f_k(x)$ be the function recursively defined by
$$f_k(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n^k \left(f(x, n) - \sum_{j = 0}^{k-1}\frac{f_j(x)}{n^j}\right)$$
where $f_0(x) = e^x$.

My plan of attack is write out $f(x, n)$ and rearrange terms to pull out factors of $\frac{1}{n^j}$.  Hopefully the coefficients of these powers will be easily identifiable power series.  Instead of remaking the wheel though, is this a well known expansion? Are there any suggestions for how to make this an easier task?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to understand everything correctly, you want corrections to the leading $e^x$ term, right?

Comment: @tired   Yes, I want to iteratively read off functions that die like $1/n^k$.  So $f_1(x)$ should come from: $\lim_{n \to \infty} n (f(x, n) - e^x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I have a couple of unpleasant ways to offer; someone else may be able to improve on them.

1. Start with $e^{-x}(1+x/n)^n$, and do a series expansion about $x=0$. This will give you a series where you get powers of $n$ in the denominator, but more importantly, you only have to go to the $2k$th term to get the full expansion for the $k$th power of $n$. (There should be a simple proof of this, but for the moment it eludes me.)
2. Take the logarithm, subtract $x$, and use the power series
   $$ n\log{(1+x/n)}-x = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} \frac{x^k}{kn^{k-1}} $$ and now use the [exponential formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_formula) to recover the power series of the exponential. This requires that you look up the Bell polynomials, but from there it is straightforward and algorithmic, if not necessarily as closed a form as you would like.